# Fetching data on component did mount with async await doesnt wait

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

Im trying to get some data on componentDidMount to set the state in react.

Im using asyn await on componentdidMount, fetch some data, await for it, and when its done set my state to the data.

Im following the exact same pattern in this article: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/async-await-with-react-lifecycle-methods-802e7760d802

this is my componentDidMount method:

```
  const url = "http://localhost:3001";
  const opts = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query })
  };
  await fetch(url, opts)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({
      photographers: data
    }))
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

then in my render method i try to use the state value.. but its undefined:

```
render() {

console.log('here:', this.state)

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div className="red ba">Hella!</div>
    <List photographers={this.state.photographers}/>
  </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Ive used asunc await many times before, i know how it works, butwhy is this not working? thanks!

Comment: You don't need to use `await` in  your example code for `componentDidMount` becuase you never use the result in the method itself. Also `componentDidMount` fires after component were actually mounted to the DOM. So, the first `render` already happened. And this first render obviously would see initial state before anything were fetched.

Answer (score 1):

You should delete .then() .catch() methods, they are returning promises, instead you should make **componentDidMount async** and **fetch await**

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      photographers: []
    }
  }

async componentDidMount() {
  const url = "http://localhost:3001";
  const opts = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query })
  };
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, opts)
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json)
    this.setState({ photographers: json });
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Also you can surround fetch with try and catch, this way you can handle errors inside the catch block or if response.ok is not true

Comment: I tried your solution, but still on my rende rmethod when i try to console.log the state is null @onuriltan

Comment: can you console.log json object before this.setState? I guess your query object is missing, where does it come from?

Comment: No i cant log anything inside the componentdidMount, but in the constructor yes.. my query is at the top of the file and its correct. @onuriltan

Comment: yes the error is that it tried to read photographers from state.. but its null... as it was suposed to be set on component did mount after fetch @onuriltan

Comment: I mean in your browsers console .. not state of the component

Comment: No there is no errors in the browser console.. the app breaks because it tries to map over the state, but its null, so it says "Cannot read property 'map' of null" @onuriltan

Comment: so you should put a check if(this.state. photographers) **in front of the** photographers.map(photographer => { ... }), because it is initially null,or make the initial photographers state as an empty array

Comment: Ok... but that part is inside of another component... i pass photographers as props, it feels ugly to have to check if that props exist.. if i pass it it should exist..right? @onuriltan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199110/discussion-between-onuriltan-and-giorgiomartini).

Answer (score 1):

This is how asynchronous javascript works, code will run to complete, what does it mean, is that while you ran a network request and wrote await in componentDidMount nothing from the next code will stop and wait, everything will continue as usual (and when the network request is complete, the code in the then code will be executed), notice that await is just a more easier way to write then blocks (nothing actually waits)

because you can not stop rendering with await, you should handle when data is not there, usually showing a loading screen, what you can do is something like this:

```
// You should initialise the photographers in the state to be null
render() {

console.log('here:', this.state)

return this.state.photographers !== null ? (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div className="red ba">Hella!</div>
    <List photographers={this.state.photographers}/>
  </React.Fragment>
  ) : (<div>Loading...</div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to combine both the syntaxes for asyncs calls - async/await and .then().catch()
Just stick to one.

Personally I prefer to put my async code in a different function and use that in componentDidMount()

```
const fetchPhotographers = () => {  
  const url = "http://localhost:3001";
  const opts = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query })
  };
  fetch(url, opts)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({
      photographers: data
    }))
    .catch(console.error);
}

componentDidMount() {
 fetchPhotographers()
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, there must be something wrong with some other part in your code. So, add the code for the whole component in here.